# Accessing elements of a data structure (array)

Tags: php, arrays

I have this dataobject, that when dumped looks like this:

```
array (
'roleid' => 5,
'contextid' => '1727',
'userid' => '229',
'component' => '',
'itemid' => 0,
'timemodified' => 1329405635,
'modifierid' => '6',
)
```

When I try to access the userid element, no problems.

```
$userid = $dataobject['userid'];
```

When I try to access either the roleid or the contextid the same way:

```
$roleid = $dataobject['roleid'];
$contextid = $dataobject['contextid'];
```

Its generating an error saying:

**undefined index:  roleid in line.... OR
undefined index:  contextid in line....**

I just don't see why this is happening.  I need to access each of the failing elements in the array.

This is the code i am using to try to access the roleid:

```
foreach($dataobject as $field=>$value){
    if($field == 'roleid'){
      $roleid = $value;
    }else{
      $roleid = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unable to duplicate on PHP 5.3.2: if `$dataobject` is defined to be the array above, then `echo($dataobject["roleid"] . "\n");` returns `5`.

Comment: Run a foreach loop and print out all the keys and values.

Comment: @Jack, roleid is a simple integer value returned from a post.

Comment: No, I'm not talking about the key `roleid`.  I'm talking about the variable `$roleid`.  There's a difference.

Answer (score 0):

The key `roleid` or `contextid` is not set somehow. Post the code and we will find out where the error is.